# mmap messing up - causing kernel to hang

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

I am building an application for an embedded board which is using Microblaze as the processor. I have Linux cross-compiled for this. The board has 512 MB of memory but the kernel knows only 256 MB of it (the lower half of DDR3).

This is the memory map of the system:

```
0x4000_0000 to 0x5FFF_FFFF -> Physical range of DDR3 (verified with cat /proc/meminfo)
0x4000_0000 to 0x4FFF_FFFF -> Known to linux and used by the kernel
0x5000_0000 to 0x5FFF_FFFF -> Mmaped using "/dev/mem" for my application
```

I have to have direct access to a region in DDR, specifically the 2nd half of the DDR. So I wrote an application that mmap's physical memory like this:

```
typedef struct 
{
  int fd;                      // File descriptor
  unsigned long *hw_addr;      // Hardware base address
  unsigned long *vaddr;        // Virtual address pointer
  unsigned long memsize;       // Size of physical region
  off_t page_offset;
  off_t page_address;
  off_t page_size;
} mem_region_t ;

mem->vaddr = (unsigned long *) mmap(0, 
                  mem->memsize, 
                  PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                  MAP_SHARED, 
                  mem->fd, 
                  mem->page_address);
```

To test the working, I am doing a simple memory test (memtest) on the requested region.

Here are some of the problems I am noticing:

1. I can allocate any amount of memory and mmap it, no problems. When I use a small region 0x100 bytes for the memtest, the test runs successfully.
2. When I allocate larger regions (0x1000, 0x1_0000, etc), the kernel does not segfault, it hangs !! Is this behavior normal ?

Can you suggest ways to work around the problem ? Am I even mmap'ing it correctly.

My suspicion is that anything smaller than a page of memory works and more than that screws up badly. Do I need to enable a feature in the kernel ?

Thanks for your attention. Let me know if you need more info.

RRS

Answer (score 2):

OK... so I solved the problem.

I saw that the kernel didnt have enough pages for my work. So I created a no-go zone using "memmap" (see kernel parameters). This allowed me to use the mmap mentioned above.

It seems to work well for large allocation of contiguous physical memory.